# Doubled system tray icons in Xfce

Tags: centos, rhel, xfce, icons, tray

I have `Red Hat` based system with `Xfce` DE and installed `Skype` last version from official site. When I running it (only once, with one user account) in system tray I seeing doubled `Skype` icon, and not only `Skype` as you can see on the screenshot.

**How to get rid of the icon's duplicate?**

[image: screenshot]

---

#### My systems:

- RHEL 7.5
- Centos 7.5
- Xfce 4.12
- Skype 8.28
- Telegram desktop 1.3

Latest software for today..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned here: [System tray icon in xfce - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/system-tray-icon-in-xfce/d3f162bf-0bbf-481b-90a1-f43cae9a86cc?page=5) - there was same issue on Fedora 28 with GNOME desktop.

> The electron framework appears to have issues with upscaling the tray image, but does not seem to have a problem with downscaling the image. So an alternative work-around for the current situation is to replace the small (16px) images with larger versions - and I suspect that even without this issue, in most cases, downscaling a 256px icon to (arbitrary) target tray size will look nicer than upscaling the extra small icons.
>
> Until this is fixed in electron or worked around in skype by using larger icons by default, you can work around it yourself. To do so, one needs to unpack `/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar` (using electron asar tool), replace the images in `<unpacked-dir>/app/images/tray/linux/`, and pack it back. The tray icons are already provided in two versions, 16px and 32px (HiDPI, @2x name suffix). So if your tray size does not exceed 32px, you can simply copy the 32px versions over 16px ones.

---

#### Solution by steps:

1. Install required soft

   ```
   $ sudo yum install npm
   $ sudo npm install -g asar
   ```
2. Unpack `app.asar`

   ```
   $ asar extract /usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar ./skypeapp
   ```
3. Replace smaller icons with bigger ones
4. Repack `app.asar` and replace old one

   ```
   $ asar pack ./skypeapp ./app.asar
   $ sudo cp ./app.asar /usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar
   ```

---

<sup>With slight modifications works for Debian 9 as well.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this seems to be an [issue with Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12791) (the framework behind the [new Microsoft Skype](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/system-tray-icon-in-xfce/d3f162bf-0bbf-481b-90a1-f43cae9a86cc#)) and maybe behind your other apps too.

Anyway, you have a few options as workarounds:

1. Try installing (if you haven't) libappindicator1 and libappindicator3
2. Reducing the icon size in the panel setttings (look at the last page in the Microsoft issue link above)
3. Check the session/startup options to make sure you don't have 2 instances of the same app running (I know it's an obvious one, but, it happens).

There might be other workarounds until they fix the bug in Electron.

Answer (score 0):

From the [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/system-tray-icon-in-xfce/d3f162bf-0bbf-481b-90a1-f43cae9a86cc?page=5) proposed by *astronos2007*:

```
$ sudo npm install -g asar
$ asar extract /usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar ./skypeapp
$ cd ./skypeapp/images/tray/linux
$ ls -1 | grep "@2x" | while read -r pngFile; do cp "./$pngFile" "./${pngFile//$@@2x/}"; done
$ cd ../../../../
$ asar pack ./skypeapp ./app.asar
$ sudo cp ./app.asar /usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try [liujheyu](https://askubuntu.com/users/841010/lioujheyu)'s answer on Ask Ubuntu ([see reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033599/how-to-remove-skypes-double-icon-in-ubuntu-18-04-mate-tray/1046991)):

> As a workaround, change EXEC in 
>   /usr/share/applications/skypeforlinux.desktop from
>
> `Exec=/usr/bin/skypeforlinux %U`
>
> to
>
> `Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /usr/bin/skypeforlinux %U`
>
> You have to make the same change to
>   ~/.config/autostart/skypeforlinux.desktop so that skype can stay in
>   tray everytime system reboot. However, it seems that skype will undo
>   the change of this autostart file everytime it restarts. My solution
>   is to make this file read-only, like
>
> `chmod 440 ~/.config/autostart/skypeforlinux.desktop`

Seems to work on Mate (said in the post) and Ubuntu gnome-shell (worked for me).